# How to prevent firedac post or cancel on detail record?

Tags: database, delphi, firedac

I have two FDQuery with master-detail relationship. In the AfterInsert event of the 'Master', I make an Append in detail and in the event OnBeforePost (also of the 'master') I call the 'Post' of the 'Detail' only after validating the 'Master' fields. However, I am not able to do this in this order, as FireDac executes a 'Cancel' in the 'Detail' if it does not have any changes in the 'Detail'. If there are motions, it automatically executes the 'Post'. This happens before the BeforePost event is executed because the Detail is already in 'dsBrowse' mode during this event.
Could anyone help me get around this situation? **ie how to prevent firedac from executing a post / cancel on record-detail?**
*note: I'm using Delphi XE5

Comment: Since this is a master/detail, are you first setting your join field values so that the newly appending records are joined?  If not, it sounds like the detail is being cancelled because it's no longer relevant to your situation.  You should post code, and perhaps a pic of your form so we can see your visual controls etc..

Answer (score 1):

A workaround was to make an inherited `TFDQuery` component and overwrite the `Post` and `BeforePost` event, causing the BeforePost event to run before (not amazing?) Post.

```
type
  TMyFDQuery = class(TFDQuery)
    InheritedPost: boolean; // Avoid Duplicate BeforePost Execution
...
  protected
    procedure DoBeforePost; override;
    procedure Post; override;
...

procedure TMyFDQuery.DoBeforePost;
begin
  if not InheritedPost then
    inherited;
end;

procedure TMyFDQuery.Post;
begin
  DoBeforePost;
  try
    InheritedPost := True;
    inherited;
  finally
    InheritedPost := False;
  end;
end;
```